# Error while using NSUserDefaults

Tags: nsuserdefaults

I have an app where I am only trying to call a method once no matter how many times a user runs the app. Right now I am using this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"RunOnce"]==nil)
    {
       //My method
        [defaults setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"RunOnce"];
        [defaults synchronize];
   }
```

But when I run this code I get this error:

> index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

This is my first time using NSUserDefaults so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This problem applied to another database, not this particular one.